# GameCenter Build Error on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am making iOS apps using the ranking function of GameCenter.

Until Xcode 7 build was successful & the app was able to execute.

When I build the same program source using Xcode 8, it shows errors:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Headers/GKGameSessionEventListener.h:23:102:
>   Too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

It is a part description for the following:

```
+ (void)addEventListener:(NSObject<GKGameSessionEventListener> *)listener NS_SWIFT_NAME(add(listener:)) NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
It defined the macro "add" for myself.

```
#define add(data, val, limit) {if(++data >= limit)data = limit;}
```

I commented out the "add".
As a result, this build error is no longer out.